# Equality in Conditional Jensen's Inequality

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Conditonal Jensen's Inequality says that for a convex function $\varphi$, a random variable $X$, and a sub-sigma-field $\mathcal{F}$, $E[\varphi(X)\mid \mathcal{F}] \geq \varphi(E[X\mid \mathcal{F}])$. In ordinary Jensen's Inequality, $E[\varphi(X)]\geq \varphi(E[X])$, and we have equality if and only if $X$ is degenerate (i.e., almost surely a constant) or $\varphi$ is linear. I'm wondering if an analogous result holds for the conditional version. Is it the case that $E[\varphi(X)\mid\mathcal{F}]=\varphi(E[X\mid\mathcal{F}])$ if and only if $X \in \mathcal{F}$ or $\varphi$ is linear? (Certainly the "if" is true, but I'm wondering about the "only if.")

Comment: The conditions you state for equality in ordinary Jensen are not correct.  $\varphi$ need not be linear everywhere, just on the essential range of $X$.  That will include the degenerate case.

Comment: Okay, but the question still stands. If $\varphi$ is strictly convex on the essential range of $X$, must it be that $X \in \mathcal{F}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1:** Abbreviate $Y:=E[X|\mathcal F]$. Let $g(x)$ denote the right-hand derivative of $\varphi$ at $x$. Because $\varphi$ is strictly convex, we have $\varphi(x)>g(m)(x-m)+\varphi(m)$ for all $x\not=m$. Thus,
$$
\varphi(X)\ge g(Y)(X-Y)+\varphi(Y)
$$
with strict inequality off $\{X=Y\}$ (almost surely).
Taking conditional expectations in the inequality above we obtain $E[\varphi(X)|\mathcal F]\ge \varphi(Y)$, and
$$
\{E[\varphi(X)|\mathcal F]=\varphi(Y)\}\subset\{P[X\not=Y|\mathcal F]=0\}
$$
almost surely.

**Method 2:** Let $\mu(\omega,dx)$ be a regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal F$. (Such exists because $X$ is real valued.) That is, for each Borel set $B\subset\Bbb R$, $\omega\mapsto \mu(\omega,B)$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable, for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $B\mapsto \mu(\omega,B)$ is a probability measure on $\Bbb R$, and $\int_{\Bbb R} f(x)\,\mu(\omega,dx)$ is a version of $E[f(X)|\mathcal F](\omega)$ for suitably integrable $f$. Now apply Jensen's inequality (for the strictly convex function $\varphi$) to the probability measure $\mu(\omega,\cdot)$ for each fixed $\omega$. The conclusion is that for $P$-a.e. $\omega\in\Omega$, the equality of $E[\varphi(X)|\mathcal F](\omega)$ and $\varphi(E[X|\mathcal F](\omega))$ forces $\mu(\omega,\cdot)$ to be a unit point mass at $E[X|\mathcal F](\omega)$.

Comment: It seems to me that to formalize Method 1
 one also needs to use the existence of a regular conditional distribution. Furthermore, to conclude the argument in Method 2 one should notice that $\mathbb{E}\phi(X)=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(\phi(X)|\mathscr{F})=\mathbb{E}\phi(\mathbb{E}(X|\mathscr{F}))$ for all measurable positive $\phi$, to conclude that $X=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathscr{F})$ and hence is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable.

Comment: In Method 1, as noted, we have $\{X\not=Y\}\subset \{E[\varphi(X)\mid\mathcal F]>\varphi(Y)\}$, a.s. Therefore, because $\{E[\varphi(X)\mid\mathcal F]>\varphi(Y)\}\in\mathcal F$,
$$
P[X\not= Y\mid\mathcal F]\}\le 1_{\{E[\varphi(X)\mid\mathcal F]>\varphi(Y)\}},
$$
almost surely. This proves the final assertion in Method 1, with no use of regular conditional distributions.

In Method 2, as you note, if $E[\varphi(X)\mid\mathcal F]=\varphi(E[X\mid\mathcal F])$ then $X=E[X\mid \mathcal F]$ a.s., so $X$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable, assuming completeness.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I now think my previous comment was wrong and that in both cases to conclude we need to argue as follows: from $\mathbb{E}(1_{X=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathscr{F})}|\mathscr{F})=1$ we get $\mathbb{E}(1_{X=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathscr{F})})=1$, hence $1_{X=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathscr{F})}=1$ a.e., hence $X=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathscr{F})$ a.e.